# Having trouble making a SOAP request to a Railo server and executing coldfusion function

Tags: java, web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl

I have made SOAP requests before in Java but I seem to be having an eternity of trouble with this one. 
I use SOAPUI to see what the envelope needs to consist but the function's namespace isn't declared in the object istelf but rather a namespace for the entire envelope (you'll know what i mean below)

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:kic="http://kickstart.private.webservices.public">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <kic:getStats soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <websiteUrl xsi:type="xsd:string">?</websiteUrl>
      </kic:getStats>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried both ksoap2 and xml.soap but both seem to return an html String from the webservice (redundant to post as it doesn't return a specific error).

I also tried makign the request directly from the WSDL link and calling the functions from there : http://dev.rightclick.nl/rc/public/webservices/private/kickstart/daily.cfc?wsdl

I preferably use ksoap2 because it worked for me in the past but as all examples have used Android, I wouldn't mind switching to a more appropiate replacement

My Java code looks as follows :

```
package com.rc.kickstart.backend.WebService;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.MarshalBase64;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

public class RequestService {

    private static final String WSDL = "http://dev.rightclick.nl/rc/public/webservices/private/kickstart/daily.cfc?wsdl";
    private static final String targetNameSpace = "http://dev.rightclick.nl/rc/public/webservices/private/kickstart/daily.cfc";
    // for getStatsRequest
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://rightclick.nl/webservices/private/kickstart/";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getStats";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

    private static final String ADDRESS_LOCATION = "http://dev.rightclick.nl/rc/public/webservices/private/kickstart/daily/";

    private static final String hostURL = "dev.rightclick.nl/";
    private static final String WEBSITE_URL = "http://dev.rightclick.nl/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // requestSOapObject
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("websiteUrl", WEBSITE_URL);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);
        // envelop.bodyOut = request;
        envelop.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
        envelop.dotNet = true;

        MarshalBase64 mbase = new MarshalBase64();// marshal is used to
                                                    // serialize the byte array

        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL);
        aht.debug = true;
        mbase.register(envelop);

        try {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelop);
        } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Request: " + aht.requestDump);
            System.out.println("Response: " + aht.responseDump);
        }

    }

    private final static SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        return envelope;
    }

}
```

this exact code has worked before with a similar webservice 
When running, I get this error but that is only because xml.soap tries to parse html code. :

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT 
>   Connection to T...@1:84 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4b1210ee)    at
>   org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.rc.kickstart.backend.WebService.RequestService.getStatsData(RequestService.java:67)
>     at
>   com.rc.kickstart.backend.WebService.RequestService.main(RequestService.java:28)

If you have any questions or want more info please comment.